# Transfer a MYSQL database file from Windows (WAMP) to Ubuntu (LAMP)

Tags: mysql, lamp

My Windows computer is broken and I cannot do anything with it. I managed to get access to the hard drive and I am moving some websites I'm developing but I need the database that is located in: 
wamp/www/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.x.x/data

to its respective location in Ubuntu, which I don't know what it is.

I've been trying and in windows (inside that folder I mentioned above) I see a folder per each database, and inside that folder there are a lot of .frm, .idb and other files.

When I go to /var/lib/mysql/ in Ubuntu I only see one file per each databse (not folders) and now I don't know how can I migrate this databse from WAMP and I don't have any SQL Script :/

Here's an screenshot of the difference I see between the two MYSQL folders

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTkc6.jpg

Comment: That will probably not work. I believe you need to export the database on Windows and import it on Ubuntu with mysqldump.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't because the PC is broken

Comment: The files need to be in /var/lib/mysql and I assume with the same directory structure. You will need to create the users manually though. Hope it works. A dump would be easier ;)

Comment: Any tutorial or link for mysqldump? Please? @Rinzwind

Comment: You wont get it better than this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing .frm files in the  windows is that the .frm files would hold the information about the column  details.There are very essentials so please follow the below steps to move the old MySQL folder from WAMP to LAMP.

(i) Copy the data folder alone fully from WAMP location wamp/www/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.x.x/ to any desired location in LAMP say (/home).

(ii)Then stop the MySQL in the LAMP and then open the my.cnf file located in the /var/lib/mysql/.

(iii) Search for data dir and then edit the location to /home which has the data directory of mysql of WAMP  machine.

(iv) Now rename the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 in the /var/lib/mysql/ location and then restart the mysql.

(v).Now try to login into the MySQL using the credentials and then try to access the database using select query.